# Attaching duplicate existing entities to a new entity

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a projects table which has three associations to the contacts table, one for each type of contact (Sponsor, Broker, Logistics).   I allow a user to select from an existing list of contacts. If the same contact is selected for two or more of these my code gets them correctly pointed to the existing entry, but I get a new unused contact entry in the database.

I only allow the first of any duplicates to be modified, I assemble them detached and then attach to the DbContext prior to saving.

```
if (newProject.SponsorContact != null && newProject.SponsorContact.Id > 0)
    if (AttachContact(newProject.SponsorContact))
    SdContext.Entry(newProject.SponsorContact).State = EntityState.Modified;
    else
    newProject.SponsorContact = _contactDataMapper.GetContactById(newProject.SponsorContact.Id);


if (newProject.BrokerContact != null && newProject.BrokerContact.Id > 0)
    if (AttachContact(newProject.BrokerContact))
    SdContext.Entry(newProject.BrokerContact).State = EntityState.Modified;
    else
    newProject.BrokerContact = _contactDataMapper.GetContactById(newProject.BrokerContact.Id);

if (newProject.LogisticsContact != null && newProject.LogisticsContact.Id > 0)
    if (AttachContact(newProject.LogisticsContact))
    SdContext.Entry(newProject.LogisticsContact).State = EntityState.Modified;
    else
    newProject.LogisticsContact = _contactDataMapper.GetContactById(newProject.LogisticsContact.Id);
```

AttachContact just keeps track of the attached contact id's and returns false if already attached so that I can grab the existing contact from the context.

```
protected bool AttachContact(Contact contact)
{
    if (!_attachedContacts.Contains(contact.Id))
    {
    _attachedContacts.Add(contact.Id);
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So if I choose Jacob Marley with ContactId 17 twice, my project saves with both entries pointing to the correctly modified Jacob Marley id 17, but I get a new Jacob Marley also saved in the contact table with no project pointing to that entry.   Giving serious consideration to accessing the context during assembly so I know existing entries are already attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to C# MVC and entity framework.  This may be common knowledge, but if you are reading this your likely having the same issue I have described above.

**The key elements are that the model in question has multiple fields that reference the same foreign table and during assembly these were detached models**.  In my case I have a project table which has three different types of contact and a user may select existing contacts for this which could mean that the same foreign contact is used for all three fields.

So the Project model has an int foreign key field for each one AND a virtual model.

```
public Nullable<int> SponsorContactId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> BrokerContactId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> LogisticsContactId { get; set; }
public virtual Contact SponsorContact { get; set; }
public virtual Contact BrokerContact { get; set; }
public virtual Contact LogisticsContact { get; set; }
```

Because I built my assembler to cascade down from Organization to Project to Contacts I was unable to assemble the contacts as attached.

There are two ways this can be solved.

The first is to make sure that you assemble them as attached, meaning you get the contact model from the context instead of creating a new contact model.

The second is the route I took.  I only allowed a user to edit one of the same contact on the front end and in the view model I tracked if it was modified. During assembly if the contact was existing, meaning it had an Id > 0, I would only assemble the virtual contact if it was also modified.  If it was not modified I just populated the int value.  So if Sponsor Contact is existing but not modified I set int SponsorContactId and did not assemble the Contact SponsorContact.

If you have any questions please post a comment.  I check in regularly and will get back to you.